# Can't read some files from camera roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I wrote simple library to get photos from camera roll. Unfortunately can't read some of them. I can't preview or convert to NSData

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
options.includeAssetSourceTypes = PHAssetSourceTypeUserLibrary;

PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:options];

PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptionForPhotos = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
requestOptionForPhotos.networkAccessAllowed = YES;

for(PHAsset *asset in allPhotosResult) {
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
    requestImageForAsset:asset
    targetSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
    options:requestOptionForPhotos
    resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {

        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(result);
        NSString *base = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed]; // for some of photos there is nil
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information on the problems you are having

Comment: I got collection of photos, but part of them is unreachable. As I wrote above, can't preview or get NSData.